# Find the difference between two text fields in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sentences which are different from each other. See sentences below

```
*,user,rollbacker,accountcreator
*,user,accountcreator,rollbacker,sysop
```

The first sentence is located in cell A1 and the second is in cell A2.
As you can see, the second sentence has `sysop` which will be the difference.
I want to show in cell B2 the word `sysop`.

I have tried `TRIM` and `SUBSTITUTE` but it did not work because the sentences are not arranged the same way when it comes to `rollbacker,accountcreator` in the first sentence and `accountcreator,rollbacker` in the second sentence.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the second one always the one with extra words or will both have words not found in the other? Will the words always be separated by a comma?

Comment: the next cell after the second sentence might have less words. And the words are always separated by a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Split both the strings by the commas into two arrays,  then looping through each array replace any identical words with blanks.  Then add the two strings together and place them in the desired cell.

Like this:

```
Dim fArr() As String
Dim SArr() As String
Dim fStr As String
Dim sStr As String
Dim aStr As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

fStr = Range("A1").value
sStr = Range("A2").value

fArr = Split(fStr, ",")
SArr = Split(sStr, ",")

For i = LBound(fArr) To UBound(fArr)
    sStr = Replace(sStr, fArr(i) & ",", "")
    sStr = Replace(sStr, fArr(i), "")
Next i
For j = LBound(SArr) To UBound(SArr)
    fStr = Replace(fStr, SArr(j) & ",", "")
    fStr = Replace(fStr, SArr(j), "")
Next j

If Trim(fStr) <> "" And Trim(sStr) <> "" Then
    Range("B2") = fStr & "," & sStr
ElseIf Trim(fStr) = "" Then
    Range("B2") = sStr
Else
    Range("B2") = fStr
End If
```

Comment: A very clever approach!

Comment: Hmm. OP did you want all of the output to display into cell B2, no matter what? I took the approach that B1 should display anything from A1 that was not in A2... and likewise B2 should display anything from A2 that was not in A1. You  picked this answer, so perhaps this is what you wanted, but that was not clear in your question and it seems less useful.

Answer (score 1):

I like Scott's answer, but I had written this more literal-minded approach in the mean time:

```
Public Function CompareCSVStrings(strA As String, strB As String) As String  

Dim varA As Variant  
Dim varB As Variant  
Dim strResults As String
Dim strTest As String

Dim blnDifference As Boolean

Dim intIndexA As Integer
Dim intIndexB As Integer

varA = Split(strA, ",", , vbTextCompare)
varB = Split(strB, ",", , vbTextCompare)

'Look for values in strA that are not in strB
For intIndexA = LBound(varA) To UBound(varA)
    vstrTest = varA(intIndexA)
    blnDifference = True 'assume not present in second array
    For intIndexB = LBound(varB) To UBound(varB)
        If StrComp(varB(intIndexB), strTest, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            blnDifference = False 'this string is not a difference after all
        End If
    Next intIndexB
    If blnDifference Then strResults = strResults & "," & strTest
Next intIndexA

'Look for values in strB that are not in strA
For intIndexB = LBound(varB) To UBound(varB)
    strTest = varB(intIndexB)
    blnDifference = True 'assume not present in second array
    For intIndexA = LBound(varA) To UBound(varA)
        If StrComp(varA(intIndexA), strTest, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            blnDifference = False 'this string is not a difference after all
        End If
    Next intIndexA
    If blnDifference Then strResults = strResults & "," & strTest
Next intIndexB

CompareCSVStrings = strResults

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very direct way to do it:

```
Public Sub ShowDiff()
    [b1] = Diff([a1], [a2])
    [b2] = Diff([a2], [a1])
End Sub
Private Function Diff(a$, b$) As String
    Dim m&, n&
    m = 1
    a = "," & a & ","
    b = "," & b & ","
    Do
        n = InStr(m + 1, a, ",")
        If n Then If InStr(b, Mid$(a, m, n - m + 1)) = 0 Then Diff = Diff & "," & Mid$(a, m + 1, n - m - 1)
        m = n
    Loop Until n = 0
    Diff = Mid$(Diff, 2)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using a dictionary

```
'Reference Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Dim intCounter1 As Integer
Dim strArr1() As String
Dim strArr2() As String
Dim strDif As String
Dim dict1 As Dictionary
Dim varKey As Variant

strArr1 = Split(Cells(1, 1).Value, ",", , vbTextCompare)
strArr2 = Split(Cells(2, 1).Value, ",", , vbTextCompare)
Set dict1 = New Dictionary

For intCounter1 = LBound(strArr1) To UBound(strArr1)
    If dict1.Exists(strArr1(intCounter1)) = False Then
        dict1.Add Key:=strArr1(intCounter1), Item:=1
    End If
Next intCounter1

For intCounter1 = LBound(strArr2) To UBound(strArr2)
    If dict1.Exists(strArr2(intCounter1)) = False Then
        If Len(strDif) = 0 Then
            strDif = strArr2(intCounter1)
        Else
            strDif = strDif & ", " & strArr2(intCounter1)
        End If
    End If
Next intCounter1

Cells(2, 2).Value = strDif
```